# Number of combinations/groups possible?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can I combine/group N items? Example of what I mean:

Items a,b,c:
(abc) / 
(ab)(c) / 
(a)(bc) / 
(ac)(b) / 
(a)(b)(c) = 5
where parenthesis mean a group distinct in some way from the others.

Or for items a,b,c,d,e,f one might have: 
(ae)(b)(cdf)

In other words, all breakdowns, of variable group sizes.

(I did search, but either it hasn't been dealt with here or I do not know the correct mathematical terminology.)

Comment: The mathematical term is "[set partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)." The number of ways to partition a set with $n$ elements is $B_n$, the $n$th [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) (not to be confused with Bernoulli numbers).

Comment: @anon Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Comment: What questions are you referring to?

Comment: Ok. Followed your link to wikipedia. Just what I was looking for. Thanks.